# Does Gmail support for RFC 821?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, c#-3.0, gmail

Does Gmail support RFC 821? I know it is using ESMTP. Based on understanding ESMTP is RFC 1869. But I must use RFC 821 commands with C# and want to test it. If Gmail doesn't provide support, is there any server provides this service for developers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RFC1869 defines a set of *extensions* to the SMTP protocol that a server can support. They come in addition to the standard SMTP protocol described in RFC 821. In other words, any server that supports RFC 1869 must also support RFC 821. The newer standard makes this explicit:

> 4.1.  Changes to STD 10, RFC 821
>
> This specification is intended to extend STD 10, RFC 821 without
>      impacting existing services in any way.  The minor changes needed are
>      enumerated below.

If a client connects to such a server and issues a standard `HELO` command, it should get a server that speaks SMTP. If you need to use any of the SMTP extensions, though, you need to instead issue the extension command `EHLO`, which indicates a client that also speaks RFC1869.

However, just because the server speaks SMTP doesn't mean it's going to speak it *with you*. In particular, the server may require authentication as per RFC 4954 (e.g. require an AUTH LOGIN or similar command, or a STARTTLS command for encrypted communication). If you fail to properly authenticate before issuing a command, the server could legally send an SMTP error. While this error would be a legal SMTP response per RFC 821, that's probably not going to help you out very much.

Comment: Thanks ..you are correct but i got this confusion ,because google need AUTH PLAIN command .Also command patterns which we are sending are little bit different.I tried normal RFC 821 commands but it faild.Are AUTH PLAIN,EHLO RFC 821 command?

Answer (score 1):

RFC 1869 (ESMTP) is a refinement of RFC 821 (SMTP), not a separate protocol. You can still talk basic SMTP to an ESMTP server -- in fact, ESMTP servers are required to support it.

Since it sounds like you're trying to build something that interoperates with GMail SMTP, keep in mind that it's not intended for use by anything other than a desktop mail client. Trying to send bulk mail via GMail will end badly.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Internet Service (connectivity) Providers (ISPs) offer an SMTP server for their customers to use to send email. Your ISP's help page undoubtedly explains how to do this -- it probably mentions something like smtp.comcast.net or smtp.whatver.net.

It is quite likely, though, that they won't let you send more than a certain number of email messages per day through that port. And, they certainly won't let you send any messages through it unless you're on a machine on their network.

You may also be able to use gmail's smtp server. But, in order to do this your client software will need to be able to use TLS, port 587, and authentication (using your gmail username and password).  See here:
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86374

This need for authenticated and encrypted communication with the smtp server could prove to be quite a pain in the neck for your work of debugging.  Best to find an open SMTP server you can test things with.

The good news: RFC821 is pretty doggone simple.

Comment: Thanks....If i use TLS can i use other mail servers which are only supported fro RFC821?.Actually i am creating this for my education purpose.

Comment: TLS is an extension to RFC821.  If your assignment is to develop a simple RFC821 client from scratch, don't bother with TLS or authentication; they are harder to handle than the email protocol itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo can send email to rfc821 mail server.

And another tool that is amazin is https://www.wormly.com/test_smtp_server